# JSON Parse Bank Holiday Calendar

Tags: c#, json

I have a ASP MVC project that is accessing an API to get bank holiday dates: https://www.gov.uk/bank-holidays.json

When I parse the JSON however I am getting problems when I try to get down to the level of the 'events'. Currently I have:

```
var json = new WebClient().DownloadString("https://www.gov.uk/bank-holidays.json");
JavaScriptSerializer serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
var test = serializer.Deserialize<Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, object>>>(json);
```

I can't seem to be able to cast the final object in this deserializer to anything meaningful. I have tried a variety of objects, lists, arrays etc but nothing seem to work. I only ever seem to be able to cast it to object.

Ideally I'd like the JSON to be parsed to a meaningful object such as:

```
public class BankHoliday
{
  public DateTime Date { get; set; }
  public string Title { get; set; }
  public Country CountryCode { get; set; }
  public string Notes { get; set; }
  public bool Bunting { get; set; }
}

public enum Country
{
  EnglandWales,
  Scotland,
  NorthernIreland
}
```

I thought this would be fairly simple but I have tried everything. I'm sure it's something simple that I am missing.

Thanks

Comment: PLEASE don't use the deprecated JavaScriptSerializer! Even Web API uses Json.NET. JavaScriptSerializer was built before JSon was standardized. Besides, why are you trying to deserialize to dictionaries instead of concrete classes, eg countries, divisions, events?

Comment: A other way instead of the json api is use nager.date nuget package, you have also Support for uk [nager.date](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Nager.Date)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Don't use `JavaScriptSerializer` better choice is [JSON.NET](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json)

On site [json2csharp.com](http://json2csharp.com/) you can generate classes from JSON:

```
public class Event
{
    public string title { get; set; }
    public string date { get; set; }
    public string notes { get; set; }
    public bool bunting { get; set; }
}

public class EnglandAndWales
{
    public string division { get; set; }
    public List<Event> events { get; set; }
}

public class Scotland
{
    public string division { get; set; }
    public List<Event> events { get; set; }
}

public class NorthernIreland
{
    public string division { get; set; }
    public List<Event> events { get; set; }
}

public class RootObject
{
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "england-and-wales")]
    public EnglandAndWales EnglandAndWales { get; set; }
    public Scotland scotland { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "northern-ireland")]
    public NorthernIreland NorthernIreland { get; set; }
}
```

And then deserialise it with this way:

```
RootObject rootObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(output);
```

**EDIT**
Added properties in `RootObject` to handele bad names.
Tested on simplified JSON:

```
{
    "england-and-wales": {
        "division": "england-and-wales",
        "events": [{
            "title": "New Year’s Day",
            "date": "2012-01-02",
            "notes": "Substitute day",
            "bunting": true
        },
        {
            "title": "Good Friday",
            "date": "2012-04-06",
            "notes": "",
            "bunting": false
        },          
        {
            "title": "Boxing Day",
            "date": "2017-12-26",
            "notes": "",
            "bunting": true
        }]
    },
    "scotland": {
        "division": "scotland",
        "events": [{
            "title": "2nd January",
            "date": "2012-01-02",
            "notes": "",
            "bunting": true
        },
        {
            "title": "New Year’s Day",
            "date": "2012-01-03",
            "notes": "Substitute day",
            "bunting": true
        },                  
        {
            "title": "Boxing Day",
            "date": "2017-12-26",
            "notes": "",
            "bunting": true
        }]
    },
    "northern-ireland": {
        "division": "northern-ireland",
        "events": [{
            "title": "New Year’s Day",
            "date": "2012-01-02",
            "notes": "Substitute day",
            "bunting": true
        },
        {
            "title": "St Patrick’s Day",
            "date": "2012-03-19",
            "notes": "Substitute day",
            "bunting": true
        },      
        {
            "title": "Boxing Day",
            "date": "2017-12-26",
            "notes": "",
            "bunting": true
        }]
    }
}
```

Comment: that's great, thanks. Any ideas about how to handle the bad naming convention? I could do a simple string replace once I have the json string back from the api

Comment: I changed `RootObject` to handle it.

Answer (score 0):

I would greatly encourage you to use json.net lirary

I think you key problème here is that you need to use your type (BankHoliday) in the type definition:

```
Dictionary<string, <Dictionary<string, BankHoliday>>
```

Comment: Had this exact issue, I now have it working based on the accepted answer here, many thanks

Answer (score 0):

Why not just use [dynamic](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/dynamic)?

```
public IHttpActionResult BankHolidays()
    {
        var rawJson = string.Empty;
        using (var webClient = new WebClient())
        {
            webClient.Encoding = Encoding.UTF8; // Expected Content-Type response is "application/json; charset=utf-8"
            rawJson = webClient.DownloadString("https://www.gov.uk/bank-holidays.json");
        }
        dynamic json = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<dynamic>(rawJson);
        return Ok(json);
    }
```

Comment: `dynamic` should be avoided if possible, since it's considerably slower over having a concrete class definition. In this case, the data structures for `BankHoliday` and `Country` are known and very unlikely to change, so `dynamic` really isn't needed.

Comment: Fair point, if performance is of the utmost importance. Still have to consider technical requirements however, such as interop with non-statically typed languages (e.g. Python)